# Is it possible to prove Euler's formula from the gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know this is a bit vague but $\Gamma({1\over 2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$ made me wonder whether it's possible to prove $e^{i\pi}=-1$ using the $\Gamma(z)$ function.

Comment: [A nice paper related to this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxte3Rse_QAhWmjFQKHS-OD0oQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feulerarchive.maa.org%2Fhedi%2FHEDI-2007-09.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGevGFnp--Sgd-KixgQ9be3ZH_70g)

Comment: Before you try proving it, the first question is how you want to **define** $e^{i\pi}$ (or more generally, the exponential of a complex number).